# Uncaught TypeError: event.target is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

Using React and React-Dropdown package, I keep getting this `Uncaught TypeError: event.target is undefined` error whenever I select a year.

```js
const [sYear, setSelectYear] = useState()

function newYearSetter(event) {
  setSelectYear(event.target.value)
  console.log(event.target.value)
}

return (
  <Dropdown
    options={years}
    value={sYear}
    onChange={newYearSetter}
    placeholder="Select a year"
  />
)
```

Comment: Where does `Dropdown` come from? Its possible it doesn't pass an event to the `onChange`.

Comment: Comment out the setState method and just `console.log(event)`, do you get anything?

Comment: Its not a very good sign of package maturity when they don't document the `onChange` handler... I think the general assumptions of answerers is likely though, that it only passes the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this package](https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown) doesn't pass in the event but only the changed value of the new selected option:

https://github.com/fraserxu/react-dropdown/blob/master/index.js#L96-L100

So you will have to change your code to something like this:

```
const [sYear, setSelectYear] = useState();

function newYearSetter(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
}

return (
  <Dropdown
    options={years}
    value={sYear}
    onChange={newYearSetter}
    placeholder="Select a year"
  />
)
```

Comment: This seems right and a good reference to the source code since there's no good documentation. Not sure why it got a downvote.